# Adding a HTML Control IN C# in a web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I want to add a html control in C# which will display all the text from an html page selectively with the title given in my html page

Comment: What you want to do is not sufficiently explained. Give more detail and be as specific as possible please. You can't add HTML controls IN C#, you mean you want to use C# TO add HTML an control to a page, presumably? Where on the page? What is 'all the text'? What is 'selectively with the title'? Or do you want to create a custom control? And so on...

Comment: I wan to add the html control in such a way that it should display the text from the html page also it should provide the user with the html control on that page in such a way that user can editand update it.. the old way of writing the code will become very wrong hence wanted to use the html control for the web page

Comment: i m using C# for the project in asp.net this page is a part of my project

Comment: Your lack of real detail is still an abundance.

Comment: When you say "an HTML Control", do you mean a control which will display the contents of another web site?

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that when you are programming in ASP.NET, you are really programming in HTML. ASP.NET controls have their effect by generating HTML, which is then sent to the browser.

This changes your question. Your question is really, "how can I use HTML to display the contents of another web site, and how can I make ASP.NET generate the HTML that I need".

You can display the contents of another site by using an `iframe`:

```
<iframe id="myOtherSite" src="other site url"/>
```

You can simply place that on your ASP.NET page. However, it doesn't solve your problem with the title. I expect you can do that with some JavaScript, as your main window can access the DOM of the iframe to pick up the title and put it where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a string reader to effectively 'scrape' the page content from the 3rd party site. Then use a simple regular expression check to grab the page title. You could then do with it as you want.